# How to create forms and reports using Access database and view the form in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, access

I need to create forms and reports using access database in sharepoint 2010. Require the steps to proceed.I have created the access db first. then i created,desgined  the form using access 2010.Now i publish the form to sharepoint. My question is am unable to see the form in sharepoint. I followed the below link to get the access form in sharepoint. But after publishing am not able to see the form in sharepoint site.Below is the link which i followed see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402351.aspx). I have set the form as default view which i have created. But still my form doesnt open after publish is successfull. Suggestion required.

Answer (score 0):

Access Services allows you to upload a solution developed in Access to SharePoint so that would be worth investigating. However, this sounds like a new solution rather than an existing one so I would be tempted to see if I could use native SharePoint capability to produce the required functionality first.